# Best practices to introduce trigger-like functionality in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, triggers, event-handling, workflow

I want to introduce triggers in my rails application. By trigger i mean, automatically perform some action if a certain event occur. For example, a trigger can be defined to send email notification whenever an order is placed.

There are lot of applications already providing this functionality, for example check this article [About triggers and how they work](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408822236058-About-triggers-and-how-they-work).

My question is, what are the best practices to implement triggers in rails? Inline vs Asynchronous handling which is better?

Any kind of help is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [ActiveJob](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) in Rails.

You'll first enqueue a Job when the trigger is to be applied -> then execute this trigger through a Job in a Worker.

For example: Say you want to notify Admin as soon as a Post is created, so you'll proceed something like this:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  after_create :notify_admin
  ...

  private
    def notify_admin
      NotifyAdminJob.perform_later(id)
    end
end
```

This way, no matter how complex or time dependent your code be in `NotifyAdminJob` this will not have any impact on your Model execution (create/update)

Comment: thank you! for the answer. I'm aware of active jobs in rails, i realized that my question was not clear. I'm actually asking about best practices to implement application level triggers in rails. In case there is any helpful articles or open source project related to this.